# cant see textview items is clicked or not

Tags: android, textview

I have created the textview dynamically. My whole project is in white background so I made this textview background white. If I click one of the textview items it should take me to another activity. I got that output.

But my problem is I cant see Textview is clicked or not. I have done this through textview.setClickable(true). I can see  if it is black background. can anyone help me please

Sorry I forgot to add, My textcolor is black

Comment: what do you mean by "TextView items"? Does a TextView has items?

Comment: I am parsing xml file and displaying it in textview. thats why i mentioned it as textview items sorry

Comment: I suggest you post your code here. I couldn't picture the problem

Answer (score 0):

you have to implement onClickListener for that text field, for example:

```
       yourTextField.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Comment: yes I have already implemented onclickListener for textfield to call another activity.